# About Nbitcoin NodeBehavior

Tags: c#, nbitcoin, .net

We wrote our transaction listener and we were implement the NodeBehavior class. But when I update version of NBitcoin v3.0.0.60 to v4.1.1.46 I can't use the NodeBehavior. Because Nbitcoin cannot support to Protocol.Behaviors. What can I do? Are there another auxiliary class? Or can you suggest me another way for listen to transactions ??

Thank you for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the .Net Framework 4.5.1 to 4.5.2 and I updated again the NBitcoin after that the problem solved.